# Create an anonymous class using lambda expression?

Tags: java, java-8

Java 8 supports lambda expression, I am wondering if we could replace an anonymous class with lambda expression?

Comment: Yes, if it's replaceable by a lambda.  IntelliJ does this for me when it can.

Comment: which feature Intellij does this?

Comment: Lambda is a form of an annonymous class (with the precondition that the parent classtype is an interface with at most 1 abstract method). So what exactually do you mean with `replace an anonymous class`? Could you elaborare a bit more  maybe add an example (psuedo code) of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The idea light comes up and asks me.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) on Lambda expressions, they are the same as anonymous classes implementing functional interfaces (interfaces having only one method).

So if you have a method which takes an argument which has a functional interface as its reference type, you can use a lambda expression while calling that method. Example:-

```
public boolean testString(Predicate<String> tester, String str);
```

When calling `testString`, you can make use of a lambda expression to reduce the amount of code needed to write a comparator:-

```
boolean result = testString(s -> { /* implement Predicate.test */}, str);
```

#### Why are lambda expressions useful?

When you want to leave the core functionality of a method to the caller without writing explicit classes/anonymous classes. Expanding the example taken above:-

```
boolean isStringPalindrome = testString(s -> { /* code to check if string is palindrome */}, "madam");
boolean doesStringContainVowels = testString(s -> { /* code to check if string contains vowels */}, "abc");
```